# How do I join the LEGO Ambassador Network?

Tags: lego-group

I am a bit confused about the LEGO Ambassador Network.

How do I get free sets from LEGO? Do I have to be a content creator or can I just be a member of a community? Also how can I find a community to join?

Comment: LAN isn't some secret group you join and immediately start getting free stuff. If only it was this easy!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LEGO Ambassador here. There is an onboarding process happening every couple of months and you essentially have to get noticed by LEGO to get invited. You can also get referred by another community that already has a LAN access. But I can tell you right now that if your only goal is "to get free sets", then you're approaching it wrong and missing the point of LAN network in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

> The LEGO® Ambassador Network is a program that allows The LEGO Group
> to work with communities of LEGO fans. There are three different types
> of communities:
>
> - Recognized Online Communities
> - Recognized Fan Media
> - Recognized LEGO User Groups
>
> Anyone can create or join a group of LEGO fans but to be recognized
> they’ll need to fit a set of criteria outlined in the program.

[About the LEGO® Ambassador Network (LAN)](https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/help/more_about_us/facts_about_us/facts_about_us/about-the-lego-ambassador-network-lan-kA009000001dbqTCAQ)

The minimum requirements to join can be found on the [LAN forum](https://lan.lego.com/forums/topic/4104-the-lego-ambassador-network-rules-and-guidelines/). The basic requirements are:

- Complying with certain policies (Novelty Policy, Confidentiality Policy and IP Guidelines and several other policies)
- Must exist for a full year.
- Must have an active community with a reasonable number of people (depending on community type.

As of posting, [Bricks Stack Exchange](https://lan.lego.com/clubs/59-bricks-stack-exchange/) is one of the [110 online communities](https://lan.lego.com/index.php?app=core&module=clubs), there are also many regional user groups you can join.

Comment: This is great info, thank you!  I am at 37 sets and counting...